# Apache Shiro using two Authentications (2x shiro.ini)

Tags: apache, shiro

I want to have two Authentications pages (two login pages).

a) User: username: emailaddess   and password: password
b) Customer -> username: emailaddress  password: token in URL

But now my problem is:
How can I define this two logins?

- In need two shiro.ini correct?

I have two LoginBeans. But how can I make the a different for user / customer?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You just have to define two different Shiro realms. One for User and second for Customer.

Have a look here:

http://shiro.apache.org/realm.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I need only one shiro.ini, correct? But how can I define or set one of the realms? I think I will have two LoginBeans (LoginBeanUser and LoginBeanCustomer). How can I set the Realm for Customer and how can I set the Realm for User?

Comment: You should use authentication strategy: http://shiro.apache.org/authentication.html#Authentication-%7B%7BAuthenticationStrategy%7D%7D. You can also implement your own authenticationStrategy by extending following class: http://shiro.apache.org/static/current/apidocs/org/apache/shiro/authc/pam/AbstractAuthenticationStrategy.html.

Comment: Thank you. And how will look the Login method in this two LoginBeans?

Comment: You have to implement two realms. I guess one (for user) will be based on jdbcRealm (look it up) and the one for customers will be customRealm both interfaces provide methods for authentication which you may customize as you desire.

Comment: are there any Code examples? It would be very very helpful